# Dynamically add and remove components to a window using a remote js.

Tags: extjs, components, addition

I have created a Window in which there are a grid and tbar. I have added a menu in the tbar, and on selecting one of the menu items i want to remove the current grid and load a new grid from a file which is stored at the servers side. How can i do this.

I have tried using 'Loader' with the window. I was able to remove the child component [grid] using 'remove', but how can i access the file at the server side process it and add it as child to the window?

Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Load new data for grid data using AJAX:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/xml-grid.html

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/remote-group-summary-grid.html

Remove old grid and insert new using `remove` and `insert` functions:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window

But I think it's not the best way. If you already have grid on window, just use `store` with ajax `proxy` to get data from server.

Comment: Thank you Xupypr MV. But what is the new component to be added is a formPanel? The idea is to load the file on selecting the menu items

Comment: You can remove or add any ext component. To stay in ext notation, you can create form in your js code, just load form fields using ajax. If your form is simple you can use PropertyGrid: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/property.html